# When referring to an inanimate object, is the use of "itself" proper?

Tags: pronouns, animacy

I'm describing how to use M$ remote desktop in an email with the sentence below.

"You can use any software or hardware attached to that computer as if you were sitting at the machine itself."

The use of "itself" seems incorrect. Granted, I could end the sentence at "machine", but is there a more suitable pronoun?

Comment: Why do you think *itself* is not right?

Comment: Some might quibble about software 'installed' rather than 'attached', but the sentence *itself* is fine.

Comment: *itself* sounds incorrect because of the "self" part of the word.

Comment: `itself` doesn't imply personality. Its intended for inanimate things.

Comment: An aside.  Isn't "M$" a way to denigrate MicroSoft?

Comment: Yep. The jab is focused at the server OS, specifically requiring CALs on top of purchasing the OS license. That's a discussion for another Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of "itself" in this sentence is correct. You have used it as an emphatic pronoun, which serves to bring attention to the noun it follows. Since "machine" would be correctly referenced by the pronoun "it," the appropriate emphatic pronoun is "itself."

More reading: http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/reflexive-emphatic-pronouns/